# CS1061 error like 'xxxxxxxx(classname)’ does not contain a definition for 'updateconfirmstatus' and no extension method

Tags: asp.net, class

i have a class library with class "Customer"  having method

```
 public void updateconfirmstatus(int p, int reg_id, int status)
    {
        CustomerDac.updateconfirmstatus(p, reg_id, status);
    }
```

im using student.aspx

```
using Myproject.Business;


protected void DoctorDetails_RowUpdating(object sender,GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
Customer customer = new Customer();
```

[image]

```
}
```

Eventhough i added library to my project,and my class having method it shows me error like this

[image]

Why this happens and how to resolve this...Thank you...

**Updated Code:**

```
public static void updateconfirmstatus(int p, int reg_id, int status)
        {
           //Logic...
        }
```

Comment: Try Rebuilding the project that has reference to class library that has class Customer

Comment: i tried a lot in  rebuilding,googling but i didnt get any help..

Comment: Can you show use how you defined Customer class, is it public?

Comment: yes it is public,i have multiple methods, in that every method i got with out any struggle but this only i find difficulty.and one more thing if i add new method to that class it also shows same error but previous methods didnt show any errors

Comment: Can you show us the definition of CustomerDac.updateconfirmstatus?

Comment: Do you have a duplicity ? Perhaps you have another `Customer` class in a different namespace. Try creating a new `Customer` explicitly using the namespace it's under.

Comment: @OmriAharon i tried with diff names but vain

Comment: You code seems alright try removing temporary asp.net compiled files and restarting IIS, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17651282/how-do-you-clear-and-asp-net-app-for-compiling

Comment: @Adil i tried that also but vain.Any way thanks for your interest.

Comment: Tried reopening VS ? :)

Comment: @OmriAharon i tried reopening Vs,deleting asp.net temp files,removing bin files....but all goes vain